# Lightning Datatable sorting arrow toggle the opposite to the sorting direction

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

To put it short, my url column is working fine with the sorting function from the sever side. But the arrow next to the column header would point to the opposite direction of the sort. 
For example : an asc list the arrow would go down and vice versa
NOTE: It only happen with url column

```
    const columns = [
    { label: 'Deal Name', fieldName: 'id', type: 'url', sortable: true, typeAttributes: { label: { fieldName: 'Name',sortable: true }, target: '_self' } },
    { label: 'Account Name', fieldName: 'Account_Name__c', type: 'text', sortable: true },
    { label: 'Building Name', fieldName: 'Building__r.Name', type: 'text', sortable: true },
    { label: 'Units', fieldName: 'Unit_Numbers__c', type: 'text' },
    { label: 'Area', fieldName: 'Area_Numeric__c', type: 'number' },
    { label: 'Space Type', fieldName: 'Space_Type__c', type: 'text' },
    { label: 'Stage', fieldName: 'StageName', type: 'text' },
    { label: 'Close Date', fieldName: 'CloseDate', type: 'date' },


];

 <template if:true={data}>
            <template if:true={recordsExist}>
                <lightning-datatable 
                key-field="id" 
                data={data} 
                columns={columns} 
                onrowaction={handleRowAction}
                onsort={onClickColumnToSort}
                sorted-by={sortedBy}
                sorted-direction={sortedDirection}
                    class="slds-table_striped" hide-checkbox-column>
                </lightning-datatable>


 onClickColumnToSort(event){
    let fieldName = event.detail.fieldName;
    let sortDirection = event.detail.sortDirection;
    this.sortedBy = fieldName;
    this.sortedDirection = sortDirection;      
}
```

Any one know how to fix this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: We'd need to see some sample code in order to help you further. If you're sorting server-side, then doing something incorrectly on the client, that'd explain the problem. However, without seeing the code, all we can do is guess.

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks for the comment I just updated the code

Comment: could you also share onClickColumnToSort function

Comment: @User6670 hi, its a server call so not reallly have to create a sort function, just a event function. I updated it anyway in the original post